# Concentrated chain complexes

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-groups

Consider functors $H_n$ and $K(-, n)$, $n>1$. $$\mathbb{Z}\text{Ch} \leftrightarrows \text{Ab}. $$

And take a group morphism $G \to Q$.

I would like to compute the [Puppe Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppe_sequence) of $K(G,n) \to K(Q, n)$. Can someone help me?

It should look like:

$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \  n-1 \ \ \ \ n \ \ \ \ \ n+1  $$ 
$$\Omega(Q)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \to ... 0 \to 0 \to Q \to ...\to $$ 
$$F(f) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \to ... 0 \to G \to Q \to ...\to $$
$$k(G,n) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \to ... 0 \to G \to 0 \to ...\to $$
$$k(Q,n) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \to ... 0 \to Q \to 0 \to ...\to $$
$$C(f) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \to ... G \to Q \to 0 \to ...\to $$

But I wuold like some help in computing all maps.

Especially, the map $\Omega(Q) \to F(f)$ exists just in $\text{Ho}(\mathbb{Z}\text{Ch})$ or it's a morphism of complexes?